# Coconut oil stain in matte painted wall

Tags: walls, paint, stain

I accidentally got coconut oil on my wall a few months ago. At the time I tried everything to get it off but it wouldn't budge.

I live in rented accommodation so I will be buying paint to do touch-ups. The wall space isnt huge so I am open to painting more than just that spot if needed.

Can anyone give advice on the process or things I need to do, to prevent the oil coming through the fresh paint? (Total novice here)